# regexp match _ or no character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a small problem with JavaScript regexp.
I want to match a part of the html class, something like:

```
req_password_sameAs-myid_min-6
```

A want to match `sameAs-myid` only, but with idea that there is a possibility to not have other characters after this string for example:

```
req_password_sameAs-myid
```

is also an option.
I use this expression

```
detectCase[i].match(/sameAs-.*?(_|)/g)
```

but don't know how to tell regexp `_` or no characters as you can see.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What kind of characters are allowed after `sameAs`, exactly?

Comment: Come on, people, while this isn't a very good question yet, I don't think it deserves so many downvotes. Kaloyan has demonstrated effort and is asking an honest question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Regex quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). `_?` is the same as `_{0,1}`, means 'an underscore or nothing'.

Answer (score 1):

You should be more specific than `.*?`. *That's* your problem, not the syntactically correct (but ugly) way of making the underscore optional.

Try

```
/sameAs-[a-zA-Z]*/g
```

Comment: what tells you that his ID only contains word characters ?

Comment: @RobW: I thought he didn't want to match that ("`sameAs-myid` only").